# Calculate code run time/speed

Tags: c#, performance, time

I am very curious about run time/speed about codes in ms visual studio.

As instance,

**1. code:**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
var p = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryName);
```

**2. code**

```
var entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

If i run 1. code ı want to see "it's running time/speed 0.03 seconds"

If i run 2. code ı want to see "it's running time/speed 0.06 seconds"

Is there anything to calculate running time/speed of codes in c# without using **timer** ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Thanks.

Comment: Are you profiling the allocation speed of the CLR with the `byte[]` example? ... what purpose does that serve? ... Also, look at the `Stopwatch`.

Comment: If i debug rows , i want to calculate running time/speed of debugging duration etc etc..

Comment: Is this just for debugging/profiling? visual studio has a very handy performance analysis tool..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) for benchmarking code

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time to zip: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
```

You could create a helper method if you intend on doing using it a lot

```
public static TimeSpan Benchmark(Action action)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    sw.Stop();
    return sw.Elapsed;
}
...
var timeTaken = Benchmark(() => /* run some code */)
```

Comment: There is no anything as "StopWatch" in Winforms c# ? If i write StopWatch , there is no dll for StopWatch why can not i use it ?

Comment: @user3409638 yes there is, it's in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, just add a using to the top of your app. Or alternatively, right click `Stopwatch` in the IDE and select `Resolve` and it will do that for you.

Comment: @user3409638 it's there, it's been part of the core framework since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to use for quickly profiling code is [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) in `System.Diagonstics`

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

///.... stuff

sw.Stop();

sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

If this is something you may want to use in production, i'd recommend: http://miniprofiler.com/

Comment: There is no anything as "StopWatch" in Winforms c# ? If i write StopWatch , there is no dll for StopWatch why can not i use it ?

Comment: You will have to add a reference to System.Diagostics

Comment: its `Stopwatch` not `StopWatch`

Comment: @DaveBish there is no `System.Diagnostics` lib to reference, `System.Diagnostics` is just a namespace part of the core lib (System.dll).

Answer (score 2):

Typically one would use the stopwatch.startnew, stop, elapsedtime methods.
There are some profiling tools on the market, and microsoft also has its own built-in performance suite. The following link is a tutorial on how to set it up.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx